# Why does invertibility of the matrix $A-\lambda I$ imply that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it because invertibility of the matrix $A-\lambda I$ would imply that $A-\lambda I$  has a trivial null space, and thus there are no solutions to the equation $Ax-\lambda I = 0$ (other than the trivial solution $0$), and thus there are no eigenvalues? Does that line of thought make sense/are there mistakes with it?

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely it.

Comment: Just so. This condition is equivalent to the one you asked about in your previous question.

Comment: “...and thus there are no eigenvalues” should be “and thus there are no eigen**vectors**”

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I would have looked at the contrapositive, which says: “If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible”.  This is clear, because if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ **iff** there is some $v \neq 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$.